# SQL Server triggers - one fails one doesn't

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

We have a trigger that is dynamically generated for a set of 40 tables or so. Given the case where the trigger is on table `A`, it modifies table `B` in two ways:

1. Sets the dirty flag on existing rows in table `B`
2. Inserts any missing rows in table `B`

There is a link between the two tables such that `A`.`bID` is a foreign key to `B`.`id`.

We have come to find out this week that on at least one of the tables the trigger is failing to do step 2 (we are unsure whether it performs step 1). But it seems to be working on most of the other tables.

---

On a whim, one of our developers changed the trigger to "be more efficient." But then the problem seemed to go away...

We can't quite figure out what's different between these two triggers, any insights?

**Broken trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [A_Dirty] ON [A] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [B] SET [timeDirty] = GETUTCDATE() WHERE [id] IN (SELECT [bID] FROM inserted);
    UPDATE [B] SET [timeDirty] = GETUTCDATE() WHERE [id] IN (SELECT [bID] FROM deleted);

    INSERT INTO [B] ([id], [timeDirty])
        SELECT DISTINCT [bID], GETUTCDATE() FROM inserted
        WHERE [bID] NOT IN (SELECT [id] FROM [B])
END
```

**Working trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [A_Dirty] ON [A] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [B] SET [timeDirty] = GETUTCDATE() FROM inserted WHERE [id] = [bID];
    UPDATE [B] SET [timeDirty] = GETUTCDATE() FROM deleted WHERE [id] = [bID];

    INSERT INTO [B] ([id], [timeDirty])
        SELECT DISTINCT [bID], GETUTCDATE()
            FROM inserted
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [B]
            ON [B].[id] = inserted.[bID]
        WHERE [B].[id] IS NULL
END
```

Comment: First query uses `[B].id`, second - `[B].guid` for joining. Is it a misprint?

Comment: My apologies, that is a misprint. I have corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Are there NULL values of [id] in [B]? If so, the `NOT IN` will not work correctly. You would need to update to the following:

```
INSERT INTO [B] ([id], [timeDirty])
    SELECT DISTINCT [bID], GETUTCDATE() FROM inserted
    WHERE [bID] NOT IN (SELECT [id] FROM [B] WHERE [id] IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: The [id] field is not NULLable, so there are no NULL values present.